# How to add a class when a link has a certain label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have a series of links with no `a` classes.  I am unable to manually add any classes in the HTML...otherwise I would.  I want to use either JavaScript or jQuery to detect a certain link label and add a class to it if the match is found.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="menu-main-nav">
   <li><a href="/destination/">Duck</a></li>
   <li><a href="/destination/">Duck</a></li>
   <li><a href="/destination/">Goose</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class whenever "Goose" appears. Here is what I attempted... and failed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#menu-main-nav li a").text() == "Goose") { this.addClass("itsagoose")};
});
```

Comment: The way you're doing it above, you need a .each() loop because there's more than one result. .... or use "contains"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
$("#menu-main-nav li a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "Goose"; //<--- Only include these elements
}).addClass("itsagoose");
```

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()` if you want an exact match, and don't want to allow anything else (eg, don't match `<a><span>Goose</span></a>`).

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RWSCY/**

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [jQuery contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). That's what it's for :)

Comment: This method will also select "Not a Goose".

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use filter:

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YmWw3/)

```
$("a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "Goose"
});
```